# Add a profile picture (file upload) on My account > edit account in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a upload profile image field and save it on My account > edit account without any plugin in woocommerce.

I added the below code in `functions.php` to add the profile picture on the my account page.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_profile_imageto_edit_account_form' );
function add_profile_imageto_edit_account_form() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="favorite_color"><?php _e( 'Upload Profile Photo', 'woocommerce' ); ?>  </label>
        <input type="file" name="profile_image" id="profile_image" placeholder="Upload Profile Photo" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Suggest me anybody how to do save this data and display the saved data in edit account page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have 3 options to display a new field

1. As the first field using `woocommerce_edit_account_form_start` hook (used in my code)
2. After existing fields using `woocommerce_edit_account_form` hook
3. In a specific location, overriding [`myaccount/form-edit-account.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php) template file.

---

Functions used: to display the image.

- [`wp_get_attachment_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/) - Retrieve the URL for an attachment.
- [`wp_get_attachment_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) - Get an HTML img element representing an image attachment

*Additional CSS for the layout* may be desired

```php
// Add field
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_start() {
    ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="image"><?php esc_html_e( 'Image', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="file" class="woocommerce-Input" name="image" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
    </p>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' );

// Validate
function action_woocommerce_save_account_details_errors( $args ){
    if ( isset($_POST['image']) && empty($_POST['image']) ) {
        $args->add( 'image_error', __( 'Please provide a valid image', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors','action_woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', 10, 1 );

// Save
function action_woocommerce_save_account_details( $user_id ) {  
    if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image', 0 );

        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $_FILES['image'] . ": " . $attachment_id->get_error_message() );
        } else {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $attachment_id );
        }
   }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'action_woocommerce_save_account_details', 10, 1 );

// Add enctype to form to allow image upload
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag() {
    echo 'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );
```

---

To display the image (can be used anywhere, provided you adjust the desired hook)

```php
// Display
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form() {
    // Get current user id
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get attachment id
    $attachment_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', true );

    // True
    if ( $attachment_id ) {
        $original_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

        // Display Image instead of URL
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full');
    }
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form' );
```