# Change WordPress user profile picture based on a custom upload field from WooCommerce My account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, custom-fields

I'm using [Add a profile picture (file upload) on My account > edit account in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62021104/11987538) answer code to a add custom image upload field.

However, this uploaded image is only displayed on a user's personal profile in WooCommerce.

I would like those images also to be visible to the admin in the backend, on the user list that appears in the Wordpress dashboard (see attached images).

[image]

[image]

---

So the intention is to change the user profile picture by the uploaded image.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

By default Gravatar Image in used in WordPress. So based on:

- WordPress Development Stack Exchange - [Replace Gravatar with uploaded images?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/replace-gravatar-with-uploaded-images)
- [Add a profile picture (file upload) on My account > edit account in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62021104/11987538)

Questions and answers, you will get this updated code, which will answer your question:

```php
// Replace default Gravatar Image used in WordPress
function filter_get_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {    
    // If is email, try and find user ID
    if ( ! is_numeric( $id_or_email ) && is_email( $id_or_email->comment_author_email ) ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );
        if ( $user ) {
            $id_or_email = $user->ID;
        }
    }

    // If not user ID, return
    if( ! is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {
        return $avatar;
    }

    // Get attachment id
    $attachment_id  = get_user_meta( $id_or_email, 'image', true );
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $attachment_id  ) ) {
        // Return saved image
        return wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, [ $size, $size ], false, ['alt' => $alt] );
    }

    return $avatar;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'filter_get_avatar', 10, 5 );
```

---

WordPress functions used:

- [get_avatar()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/)
- [wp_get_attachment_image()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/)
- [is_email()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_email/)