# How do I change the wordpress directory where user images are uploaded?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I have a function for woocommerce ([Add a profile picture (file upload) on My account > edit account in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016183/add-a-profile-picture-file-upload-on-my-account-edit-account-in-woocommerce)) that allows users to upload their frontend avatars from the account> settings section. Everything works fine but the images are loaded into the default media library. Is it possible to somehow change the directory by creating a new one for the purpose?

I appreciate any help and thank you for any replies.

Here is my code:

```
// Add field
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_start() {
    ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="image"><?php esc_html_e( 'Image', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="file" class="woocommerce-Input" name="image" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
    </p>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' );

// Validate
function action_woocommerce_save_account_details_errors( $args ){
    if ( isset($_POST['image']) && empty($_POST['image']) ) {
        $args->add( 'image_error', __( 'Please provide a valid image', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors','action_woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', 10, 1 );

// Save
function action_woocommerce_save_account_details( $user_id ) {  
    if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image', 0 );

        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $_FILES['image'] . ": " . $attachment_id->get_error_message() );
        } else {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $attachment_id );
        }
   }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'action_woocommerce_save_account_details', 10, 1 );

// Add enctype to form to allow image upload
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag() {
    echo 'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this, I don't know if it's correct and practical but it's working.

```
// Add field
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_start() {
    ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="image"><?php esc_html_e( 'Image', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="file" class="woocommerce-Input" name="image" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
    </p>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' );

// Validate
function action_woocommerce_save_account_details_errors( $args ){
    if ( isset($_POST['image']) && empty($_POST['image']) ) {
        $args->add( 'image_error', __( 'Please provide a valid image', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors','action_woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', 10, 1 );

// Save
function action_woocommerce_save_account_details( $user_id ) {  
    if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image', 0 );

        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $_FILES['image'] . ": " . $attachment_id->get_error_message() );
        } else {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $attachment_id );
        }
   }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'action_woocommerce_save_account_details', 10, 1 );

// Add enctype to form to allow image upload
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag() {
    echo 'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );
```

Answer (score 1):

the thing with WordPress is that avatars are quite weird. I would suggest adding a plugin for this that uploads avatars since the container for them is different then and it might show up. The problem you have is that the image goes to another container. Overall all images on a site will be uploaded to the gallery

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to change the default location of an uploaded file. If this is the case, go to the `wp-config.php` file in the root directory and specify an address like this:

```php
define( 'UPLOADS', 'blog/wp-content/uploads' );
```

For detailed information, you can visit the official `wp-config.php` page of WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I appreciate it. I want to change the directory only for avatars that are uploaded by users and not for any files.

Comment: Maybe this one can help: 

[Can I Change the Media Upload Location for each user?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239120)

Comment: Thanks again. But I'm not quite sure how to apply in my case, could you help me with an example answer?